# Examples for Apache Commons HttpComponents

Tags: java, http, web, apache-commons, apache-httpcomponents

The [official HttpCore examples](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/examples.html) use a lot of deprecated methods (i.e. [deprecated constructors](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-dev/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/protocol/HttpService.html)). Are there any state-of-the-art examples (HttpCore 4.3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I was wrong. There are also [examples for 4.3](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/examples.html) on the offical website.

Comment: They look horribly complicated though... I was able to create an HttpClient in a non-deprecated way using HttpClientBuilder.create().build()

Comment: Oh, and I just realized that those examples were for httpcore only, and there are examples for HttpClient too in the same area.